# Calculating the probability of a set of numbers appearing in a randomly-generated 3x3 grid

Tags: probability

A challenge within a PC game I play features a 3x3 grid which contains all numbers from $1$ to $9$ in a random order. For example, this may be what a randomly-generated 3x3 grid looks like:

```
   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
  |     |     |     |
  |  5  |  3  |  1  |
  |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
  |     |     |     |
  |  9  |  7  |  6  |
  |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
  |     |     |     |
  |  2  |  8  |  4  |
  |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
```

The aim of the game is to select a single row, column or diagonal whose sum will reward a variety of goodies. Getting the a sum of $6$ (from the numbers $1$, $2$ and $3$) offers the best rewards. Unfortunately our example grid doesn't have any rows, columns or diagonals which add up to $6$:

```
 
  16     18    9    11     10
       _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
      |     |     |     |
  18  |  7  |  3  |  8  |  18
      |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
      |     |     |     |
  20  |  9  |  5  |  6  |  20
      |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
      |     |     |     |
  7   |  2  |  1  |  4  |   7
      |_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|

  10     18    9    11     16
```

The number order is [completely randomised](https://xkcd.com/221/) every time the game is played. What is the probability of a row, column or diagonal adding up to $6$?

Comment: Think about how many rows, columns and diagonals there are, think about how many ways you can arrange the numbers $1,2$ and $3$ in those rows, columns and diagonals and then think about the total number of possible grids..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are eight rows/columns/diagonals where we can place 1,2,3.  Then there are $3!$ orders we may place $1,2,3$ on that line.  Then there are $6!$ orders to place the other numbers in the other squares.  Hence the answer is $$\frac{8\cdot 3!\cdot 6!}{9!}=\frac{34560}{362880}=\frac{2}{21}\approx 9.5\%$$